# Set format view Export PDF using MPDF in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf, export-to-pdf

i try to export my costumes Sticker, i have set in my view HTML using position:relative; to set possition image and text other,
[My view in  browser is oke,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlJPZ.png)

my code view plant_v in html

```
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            color: black;
            display: table;
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container {
            position:relative;
            width: 260mm;
            height: 150mm;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        img {
          position:relative;
        }
        .gambar_qrcode {
            position: absolute;
            width: 4.8cm;
            height: 4.9cm;
            right: 187px;
            top: 130px;
        }
        .judul_nama{
          position:absolute;
          font-family: Lucida Console;
          color: black;
          font-size: 1.5cm;
          left: 50px;
          top: 150px;
            }
        .nama_latin{
          position:absolute;
          color: black;
          font-family: Lucida Calligraphy, Lucida Handwriting, WhisperWrite, Brush Script MT;
          font-style: italic;
          font-size: 1cm;
          left: 40px;
          top: 230px;
        }
    </style>
```

and my code export MPDF is

```
public function cetak($tanaman)
{

$id = decode_url($tanaman);
$data['tanaman'] = $this->tanaman->get_tanaman_by_id($id);
  // Define a page size/format by array - page will be 190mm wide x 236mm height
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [260, 150]]);
  $html = $this->load->view('plant/export_v',$data,TRUE);
  $mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
  // $mpdf->Output("".$id.".pdf" ,'D');
  $mpdf->Output("".$id.".pdf" ,'I');

}
```

but after export to PDF using mPDF [this my view after export to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTk39.png)

Comment: Hey, have you checked this out https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html. These are lists of CSS supported by mPDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed positioning is limited in MPDF, and it seems like `position: relative;` is not [supported](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/fixed-position-blocks.html).

As an alternative you can use **negative margins**:

```
<img src="img.jpg" style="float: left; margin: #Negative margin# " />
```

And instead of using `absolute` positioning, you can try to use `float` positioning.

Comment: [@ubay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9591514/ubay) Have you solved your problem yet?